# How do I push to a multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need a simple multidimensional array but don't know how to push it. 
I need to store a string, then an integer.

string(zip code) then my integer.

93801, 123

```
$zips = array();
$i = 1;

if(isset($_POST['zip' + $i])) {
    array_push($zips, $_POST['zip' = $i] $_POST['fed' + $i]);
    $i++;
}
```

I get a syntax error on the push line, but if I add a comma it just makes the two items separate.

Comment: What is `'zip' = $i` index?

Comment: I could use a bit more explanation. I am not really sure what you mean by a multidimensional array and your example.

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen It means i need a multidimensional array. there's an example under my initial paragraph. I need to store the zip code and an integer together. Instead of just an array of zips codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the values into an array with `array()` and push that into the `$zips` array.

```
array_push($zips, array($_POST['zip' + $i], $_POST['fed' + $i]));
```

As insertusernamehere mentions, you probably want `$_POST['zip' . $i]` for concatenation :)

Comment: aha! Thank you. This one answered my multidimensional question.

Answer (score 3):

use `int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )` that takes a variable number of parameters like this

```
array_push($zips, $_POST['zip' . $i], $_POST['fed' . $i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can push it to the end as a new array:

```
$zips[] = array($_POST['zip' + $i], $_POST['fed' + $i]);
```

And I guess you mean `$_POST['zip' + $i]` instead of `$_POST['zip' = $i]` and you may also check `$_POST['fed' + $i]` for existence. And also remember that `+` is not a concatenation of strings in PHP. This will always result in `$i`. You can check this using `var_dump('fed' + $i);`. If you want to get `$_POST['fed1']` use `$_POST['fed' . $i]` instead.

Comment: Thanks :D
I finally got the multidimensional part but it wasn't running. Changing the `+` fixed it. Thank you much!